# Updating the Computer Player action turn by turn in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

Currently i am developing the board game. There are four players, one is the actual human player and other remaining three is computer player or simply a bot.

When it is the turn of human player to throw the dice. He can throw and update  the score and other thing.

But when it is the computer player turn i want everything to be updated such as throwing the dice updating score slowly so that player can see it.

What i am doing now is normal and after a human player turn, the computer player turn is updated in millisecond.

How can i do it so that it will be updated slowly and player can see it.

Comment: Add timers and delays to the update function of the computer player to break up the function so you can see parts. You could also add in text or visual indicators as to what is happening to help.

Comment: This is a pretty broad question, so maybe not a good fit for this site's Q&A format, but in general I would recommend looking into designs that use timers/delays, such as coroutines (functions that can execute over multiple frames) and possibly tweening libraries (for simple animations).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very general question and without some code it's difficult to answer but there are two main options you can look into.

1) Convert your AI method into a coroutine and then add some "WaitForSeconds" in between.

```
 IEnumerator YourMethod(){
     // Do stuff
     yield return new WaitForSeconds(time);
     // Do stuff
     yield return new WaitForSeconds(time);
     // Do stuff
     yield return new WaitForSeconds(time);
```

2) Break your Method into several methods and chain calls to one another at the end with Invoke

```
void YourMethod(){
  // Do stufff
  Invoke("YourMethod2", time);

void YourMethod2(){
  // Do stuff
  Invoke("YourMethod3", time);
```